# Color change in PyShell python does not work for me

Tags: windows, python-3.x, colors

I am new to programming so i apologise for stupid questions. I am using Python 3.5.2 on windows.

I am trying to print color in my pyShell, because as a newbee, thats where i learned to code in...i dont understand why all the examples on youtube are on windows command prompt

Anyway, I installed colorama

Code:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

and on my PyShell i get...strange characters and code all in blue.
For example:

```
[31msome red text
[42mand with a green background
[2mand in dim text
[0m
back to normal now
```

PLEASE HELP OR I WILL BRAKE MY PC.
..thanks...lol

Comment: IDLE's PyShell is a development shell, not a terminal emulator. Use the python.exe interactive shell. It's a Windows console application, which colorama supports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise Colorama using:

```
from colorama import init
init()
```

And everything works fine for your code.